# Изменение цвета текста между двумя символами, android java

Tags: java, android

Хочу узнать, как можно изменить цвет текста между двумя символами (как в какой-нибудь IDE), типа:
текст(***текст, но другого цвета***)

Comment: Для базы знаний вопрос сформулирован недостаточно внятно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, вам подойдёт Spannable - интерфейс, который описывает маркировку обычного текста.
Небольшой пример использования:

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="@color/blue"/>

val spannable = SpannableString(“Text styling”)
spannable.setSpan(
     ForegroundColorSpan(Color.PINK), 
     0, 4, 
     Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)

myTextView.text = spannable
```

[image: Результат]

[Источник на Medium](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/spantastic-text-styling-with-spans-17b0c16b4568)

Answer (score 0):

Так же можно преобразовывать html в Spannable - интерфейс:

```
String text="<font color='#FF69B4'>Text</font> <font color='blue'>styling</font>";
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Если необходимо "покрасить" цветом внутри скобок, можно сделать так:

```
public SpannableStringBuilder makeSpannable(String text) {
            SpannableStringBuilder spannable = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)");//<-- поиск текста в круглых скобках
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(spannable.toString());
            while (matcher.find()) {
                ForegroundColorSpan spanGreen = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN);
                spannable.setSpan(spanGreen, matcher.start(), matcher.end(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
            return spannable;
        }
String text="text (find1) or (find2)";
myTextView.setText(makeSpannable(text));
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

шаблон regex можно проверить на сайте https://regex101.com/